# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process

Tags: selenium, webdriver

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="G:\web scraping\projects\selenium_basics\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com")

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: Use / instead of \.